# How to skip over closing braces / brackets / parentheses in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I can't get the auto-indentations to work properly unless I use the automatic closing of braces, et al (which I don't like), and I see no option allowing one to skip over/out.

Eclipse has a configuration option for this, and Visual Studio doesn't auto-close everything by default, but rather formats the code block after manually entering the closing brace (which I rather prefer).

Surely there's something apart from going all the way over to the "End" key?

Edit / update:

As I consider it bad form to leave a question without a marked answer, would someone with more recent experience with PyCharm (I haven't used it in quite some time) weigh in with a recommendation for the best among the below solutions? Perhaps there's a newer configuration option or simple solution not yet listed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Shift + Enter** will jump past completions and drop you onto the next line.

**Ctrl + ]** will jump to the end of the current element.

This seems to work in most cases to skip past auto-completions. I find it the most versatile of the options.

**Ctrl + [** will jump you to the start of whatever code block you are in.

As previously mentioned **Ctrl + Shift + Enter** will add any extra auto-completions you might need and drop onto a new line.

Answer (score 9):

Press Ctrl-Shift-Enter to close the missing braces on the current line (if any), add the missing colon (if missing) and put the caret into the correctly indented position on the next line.

Comment: I was hoping for the same auto-indent functionality that occurs when the auto-brace-closing option is selected.  Without this option everything becomes manual and relatively time-consuming.

Comment: Indeed, PyCharm doesn't have an option for triggering auto-formatting when a closing brace is typed. Could you please describe in more detail an editing scenario where this would be useful for Python code?

Comment: I used emacs several years, but want to switch to pyCharm. I think `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` is way to hard. If you can type with ten fingers to emacs version (ctrl-e : enter) would be much easier. I think every new user will have the issue of this stackoverlow question.

Comment: So typically it will be just as easy to just type it in yourself, unless there is a long set of parens at the end of the line. This seems strangely designed, more like a reminder system than an autocompleting end-paren system.

Answer (score 3):

A college told me a solution:

First you type this:

```
def test_foo(
```

PyCharm inserts `self)` as soon as you type `(`

Current state: `^` indicates the cursor position:

```
def test_foo(self^):
```

Just type `):` and hit `ENTER`, and you are on the next line.

Since I type with ten fingers `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` is not a solution for me in such common editing operations.

Comment: So basically, it is easier to enter it yourself and not have it complete it for you. This seems poorly designed, then. :)

Comment: @neuronet I switched from emacs to pyCharm some month ago. I never ever want to go back. Did you tried pyCharm? I won't call it poorly designed.

Comment: I meant this one feature, in which you just enter the stuff manually. Overall I agree PyCharm is good (I use Spyder right now, but am looking at switching).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you dislike the auto-closing brackets? They do not disturb anyone, see:
^ specifies the cursor position

`method([a, {b: c^}])`
behaves as if no brackets were there if you insert new brackets!

insert a '}':
`method([a, {b: c}^])`
now insert a ']':
`method([a, {b: c}]^)`
now insert a ')':
`method([a, {b: c}])^`

et voila! From a users point of view, if you typed blindly, you can not tell from what you see now if the auto-closing brackets were inserted or not.

Or simply: keep the closing brackets on. IntelliJ did a great work on a lot of small things we want to have intuitively.